# Appending to a list of messagingStyle notification using flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, android-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have a messaging style notification where I need to append messages to a list of messages but I have no context about the messages which have already been shown using `.show()`.

I can get information about the active notifications using `getActiveNotifications()` but there is no information about the icons or other assets which were also used in those notifications. The [ActiveNotification](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/ActiveNotification-class.html) class does not provide any such information about the notification.

I'm able to append content to simple notifications that don't contain any media but have not been able to do so for notification styles like the BigPictureStyle or the MessagingStyle notification since I'm not able to access the media used in previous notifications.

Is it possible to somehow get information about these additional details as well? Or better yet, is there a better way to achieve the above in Flutter using [flutter_local_notifications](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications).

Comment: have you found a solution for this?